# How can i access variable inside jquery function globally anywhere in javascript?

Tags: javascript

```
const levelButtons = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="level"]');
Array.prototype.forEach.call(levelButtons, function(btn) {
  btn.addEventListener('change', function(){
   var selectedLevel = this.value;
  });
});
console.log(selectedLevel);
```

I want to use selectedLevel variable as a parameter (in place of 5000) in angularjs .

```
<tr ng-repeat="user in users | filter : searchtxt | filter: greaterThan('Fees', 5000)">
<td class="Program_Name">{{user.Program_Name}}</td>
<td class="Institute">{{user.Institute}}</td>
<td class="Fees">{{user.Fees}}</td>
```

Comment: None of this is jQuery; was this the code you intended to include in the question?

Answer (score 0):

You should define a global variable or instead you can create a function that return selectedLevel and use this return in your ng-repeat